# NextJS application - loop through items from API every 3 seconds

Tags: next.js

I am using Prismic to make a Nextjs / React app.

From the API (using SSR) I get a list of items [slice.items]

In my component, I am trying to change the item every 3 seconds

However, when I use useEffect or useState - it complains this is using Client side components.

I tried using a seperate component with lazy(), but it still complains I am using client side.

Is there a way to do this in a "nextjs" way?

Comment: Hey, Alex here from the Prismic team. 

Could you post your component code? It's easier to make sure you're not doing any client-side queries that way. 

Are you using app router or pages router? You said SSR so I'm assuming pages, but want to make sure.

If you want to use client side JavaScript to handle something, you're going to need a client component.

Answer (score 0):

You can [useSWR](https://swr.vercel.app/docs/getting-started) library developed by nextjs team:

```
npm i swr
```

then

```
import useSWR from 'swr';

const fetcher = async (url) => {
  const response = await fetch(url);
  const data = await response.json();
  console.log("data fetched")
  return data;
};

const RealTimeDataComponent = () => {
  const { data, error, isLoading } = useSWR('https://reqres.in/api/users', fetcher, {
    refreshInterval: 3000, // Refresh every 3 seconds
  });

  if (error) {
    return <div>Error: {error.message}</div>;
  }

  if (isLoading) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }


  return (
    <div>
      <p>Data: {JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default RealTimeDataComponent;
```

More options for data fetching is [here](https://swr.vercel.app/docs/revalidation#revalidate-on-interval)